# Prove the every cycle of length 3 is generated by cycles (a,b,i)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I Need to prove that every cycle of length 3 is generated by the particular cycles (a,b,i) for fixed a,b, with $1 \leq a,b,i \leq n$ For $n \geq 3$.
I tried something like listing and rearranging cycles, but I didn't come to anything useful.

Comment: Every $3$-cycle is even generated by $\{(12i)\mid i=3\cdots n\}$, because $A_n = \langle (123),(124),\ldots,(12n)\rangle$,  see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358030/set-of-generators-for-a-n-the-alternating-group).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ah I see, thanks!